# how to read a specific .Matrix file in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a .Matrix file, I have been told it is similar to .csv file, and I take a look by web browser, it looks like this:

```
%TransMat_H0004.E1.L1.S1.B1.T1
```

CLUSTER,,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,2,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,3,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,1,3,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,2,1,3,3,1,3,3,2,3,2,3,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,3,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,1,3,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,3,1,3,2,3,3,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,1,2,1,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,2,1,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,2,3,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,3,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,2,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,1,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,3,3,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,3,2,3,2,3,1,1,3,1,3,2,1,3,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,1,3,1,3,2,3,2,3,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,2,3,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,3,3,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,1,3,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,3,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,2,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,3,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,1,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,3,1,1,3,2,3,3,2,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,3,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,3,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,2,1,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,1,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,3,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,3,3,3

tSNE-1,,8.13846968090103,12.8635212043927,10.3864480425066,7.17083119797853,-72.7452686458686,-49.7960088439495,45.63460621346,-50.3693843293848,-53.2415432674881,-54.6891175204711,-46.4635164735514,4.49644447816871,3.98243750756555,-9.99729157677144,-98.1041739031645,14.4129117311442,21.8090838800674,-46.5547640077783,-65.8379505581324,39.8907136841164,45.2453417297103,-43.4054353275594,5.58370171555427,-82.6419520577671,42.7647608862027,-91.125151907502,-37.9838559192307,62.9924569510685,-69.108888726706,62.7774653919852,60.3873481045592,62.825

I tried to read it by read.csv:

> test=read.csv('TransMat_H0004.E1.L1.S1.B1.T1.Matrix',sep='' )
>
> str(test)
>   'data.frame':   33141 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ X.TransMat_H0004.E1.L1.S1.B1.T1: Factor w/ 33141 levels "A1BG,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"| **truncated**,..: 13453 31099 31100 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...

how should I read it in a right format, say, first character of 'sequence'(list?I guess?) as rowname.

Thanks in advance!

---

sorry, I cannot provide the data link because it is unpublished; but I can tell you what the data look like:

```
%TransMat_H0004.E1.L1.S1.B1.T1 
cluster,1,2,3,2,3….
tsne-
1,-41,-80…..
tsne-
2,-41,-80…..
tsne-
3,-41,-80…..
(and the rest are all started with gene name and number, such as)
genea, 0,2,1,0…
….
genez,0,2,1,0
```

my desired output is to remove the first 4 factors(cluster, tsne-1, tsne-2,tsne-3), and extract the gene transcripts matrix,such as:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: do you have a desired output in mind? can you edit the data or provide a data link, other source, so its easier to reproduce the data?

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out by this:

```
read.csv("E2.Matrix", skip=1)
```

since the first row is annotation according to the bioinfor technician who arranged the .Matrix file

Thanks! @ Stephan